# How can I get NotebookPrint to pass through the system print dialog?

Tags: printing

As near as I can tell, `NotebookPrint` goes directly to the default printer, without employing the system standard process of opening a print dialog first.

Specifically, I'd like to he able to use `NotebookPrint`, or an alternative function, `somePrintFunction` to print an arbitrary expression, `expr`, using the form

```
somePrintFunction[expr]
```

and have the standard system dialog for printing appear.

Is there a way to force `NotebookPrint` to do this? Is there some other function that does?

Comment: did you check FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["PrintDialog"]],  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["PrintOptionsDialog"]], alternatively you may set global options for the front end or Options for Notebooks then call NotebookPrint.

Comment: @s.s.o: That seems to print the whole notebook. Is there a way to get it ti print a specific expression? Which options?

Comment: Yes, if a cell is selected it'll print the selected cell only.

Comment: @No selection, I'm passing the expression to be printed as an argument to `NotebookPrint`.

Comment: I can think of only 2 options either as in the previous answer just create a new notebook or select the cell programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NotebookPrint[expr, Interactive -> True]

Comment: How did I miss that?